# Conditional Comment vs Javascript

Tags: css

Currently I am working on a webpage and need to set a style only for IE. I am using a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../IEstyles.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

Is this the best way of doing this or would using javascript be the best practice?

Comment: Not really a question. Use [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you need a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nearly the best practice. You should probably instead be checking for `[if lt IE 9]`, because IE 9 supports CSS pretty well, but *definitely* don't use browser-sniffing JavaScript. That's almost always the worst solution to a problem.

Comment: When I switched to [if IE lt 9] the following showed up on my page `<!--[if IE lt 9]> <![endif]-->` and the styling works. When I leave it as [if IE] nothing extra appears on the page and the styling also works. Any ideas?

edit: the code sample only shows on page in IE

Comment: @Ironsides24: Sorry, I meant `[if lt IE 9]`.

Answer (score 1):

[Html5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) is the site for best practices and here's what they suggest:

```html
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

This allows you to keep one stylesheet and just prepend any of the above classes to target a specific conditional hack.

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone has JavaScript enabled - HTML comments are supported in every mainstream browser that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

As this is just a stylesheet, and therefore a UI concern, I would avoid javascript and just use the conditional comments to target IE. This then also gets around the issue of people who have javascript disabled, should you try and do some kind of browser sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Conditional Comments. They prevent other browsers from having to download/run any scripts, yet have the benefit of always working for IE users.

Answer (score 0):

Using the conditional would be the best idea, as you have no guarantee that the visitor won't have javascript disabled, or scripting disabled. Where as this will only work in IE browsers, other browsers will ignore it, where as all browsers will process Javascript, whether it's for IE or not.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can be disabled, so I'd say conditional comments are the best way to serve IE-specific CSS.